# Specify different sort orders after click with jQuery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I just started using the excellent jQuery tablesorter script.  This might be a dumb question, however I cannot figure out how to specify the order in which the columns are sorted after clicking.  I am not referring to whether columns are sorted in ascending or descending order, but rather the sequence in which the columns are sorted.

For example, if a one clicks on column 2, I might want to sort by column 2, then column 4, then column 5.  However, if a one clicks on column 3, I might want to sort by column 3, then column 5, then column 4.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

--MC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess that you are asking how to sort multiple columns? or do you mean that you want the other columns to automatically sort based on the first column clicked?

If want to know how to sort multiple columns then, by default, hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key then click on the columns to sort in order. You can change this key by changing the `sortMultiSortKey` option ([demo](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-key.html)).

If you want to automatically sort multiple columns based on a chosen column, I would recommend adding sort links/buttons to do this for you, otherwise you are taking those choices away from your users. Try something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/556/)):

HTML

```
<button class="sort1">Sort 1-3</button>
<button class="sort2">Sort 4-6</button>
```

Script

```
$('table').tablesorter();

$('.sort1').click(function(){
    $('table').trigger('sorton', [[ [1,0],[0,0],[2,0] ]]);
});

$('.sort2').click(function(){
    $('table').trigger('sorton', [[ [3,1],[4,0],[5,0] ]]);
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the `sortAppend` option which basically adds the sorting of a column to the end of every sort. So if you always want a particular column sorted (e.g. producers) alphabetically AFTER the user sorts another column, just initialize tablesorter with this option:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    sortAppend: [ [3,0] ] // 4th column (zero-based index) sort appended
});
```

So if the user sorts the second column, the fourth column sort is added after. Essentially it's like triggering a sort like this: `[[ [1,0],[3,0] ]]`.

Sadly, the `sortAppend` option exists in the original tablesorter, but **the code for it is missing** ([ref](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki/Change#version-207-2011-07-17)). I have fixed this problem in my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) - see [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-sort-append.html).

Alternatively, if you want the sort to be dynamic, i.e. the `sortAppend` would change depending on the column selected, for now you'll need to bind to the `sortBegin` event to add the sort ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8cg4f/469/); [ref](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/3#issuecomment-2173484)):

```
$('table').bind('sortBegin', function(e, tbl) {

    var c = tbl.config,
        list = c.sortList;

    // add third column sort if not the initial sort, otherwise sort second column
    // (zero based index)
    list.push((list[0] && list[0][0] !== 2) ? [2, 0] : [1, 0]);

});
```

I plan on making this easier to do in the future ([see this issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/236)) when I have time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I do want to sort multiple columns automatically, based on the first column clicked.  This is for a wine retailer, so customers might want to sort by wine type (initial click on the "varietal" column, for example), but also have the producers (adjacent column) sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: Just to let you know, in the latest version of my fork, you can use the [`sortAppend`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#sortappend) option to add a different sort depending on the column.